# Не наследуется font-family для некоторых блоков

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, шрифты

Суть проблемы: css свойство `font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;` работает как надо только для `header` и `footer`, для тегов `section` почему-то выставляется шрифт `sans-serif`, а не `РТ Sans`. Т.е. не могу понять, почему для футера и хедера наследуется и находится первый указанный шрифт, а для остальных тегов - нет.

Вот часть css кода, дальше идут уже св-ва по классам. 
И то, что в HTML-файле подключено правильно (внутри блоков уже идут дивы и т.д.):

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #212b4f;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 20px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.page-footer {
  color: white;
  background-color: #212b4f;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <html lang="ru-RU">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width, height=device-height">
  <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <title>-----------</title>
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="page-header">
  </header>
  <section class="page-section page-section-1">
  </section>
  <section class="page-section page-section-2">
  </section>
  <section class="page-section page-section-3">
  </section>
  <footer class="page-footer">
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: html добавь полностью, что бы видна была структура

Comment: У вас в шапке что-то совсем не валидное, надо так: `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="ru"><head> . . .`

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в чем проблема. Моя невнимательность. через devtools и вкладку Computed увидел откуда идет сво-во и поправил в CSS. Было прописано для общего класса "page-section" font-family: sans-serif.